# Using ajax:loading appear gif dont work rails Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My request ajax dont call the function to appear the gif of loading, im use a sample ajax requisition, my js is:

```
$("#carregar").bind("ajax:loading", function(et, e){
    $(this).hide();
    $("#load_img").show();
});
```

im using the sample method of controller.js.erb and load the content but the gif dont appear please what is wrong ? thanks

Comment: I think what you are looking for is http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ajax:loading` was an event triggered by the JS driver which shipped with older versions of jquery-rails. It has since been altered. If you are using a more recent version of Rails then you should bind to the `ajax:beforeSend` event.

Other things to consider:

1) Handlers for the `ajax:beforeSend` event should be bound to the element which triggered the AJAX request, most likely a FORM element.

2) When using jQuery .bind() the target element needs to be present in the DOM. An easy way ensure the DOM is loaded before you bind event handlers is to wrap your script in document ready callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#carregar").bind(...)
})
```

3) Arun's suggestion about using ajaxStart would be good for showing and hiding the ajax loading indicator.

```
// Show and hide the indicator for every AJAX request.

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
  $("#load_img").show();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
  $("#load_img").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks this method solve to me, but thanks to all, im learn in each response, thanks  very thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) for events triggered.

Try binding the `ajax:before` event instead of `ajax:loading`.